# How to update an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, spark-streaming

We are developing Spark framework wherein we are moving historical data into RDD sets.

Basically, RDD is immutable, read only dataset on which we do operations.
Based on that we have moved historical data into RDD and we do computations like filtering/mapping, etc on such RDDs.

Now there is a use case where a subset of the data in the RDD gets updated and we have to recompute the values.

HistoricalData is in the form of RDD.
I create another RDD based on request scope and save the reference of that RDD in a *ScopeCollection*

So far I have been able to think of below approaches -

**Approach1: broadcast the change:**

1. For each change request, my server fetches the scope specific RDD and spawns a job
2. In a job, apply a map phase on that RDD - 
   2.a. for each node in the RDD do a lookup on the broadcast and create a new Value which is now updated, thereby creating a new RDD 
   2.b. now I do all the computations again on this new RDD at step2.a. like multiplication, reduction etc 
   2.c. I Save this RDDs reference back in my *ScopeCollection*

**Approach2: create an RDD for the updates**

1. For each change request, my server fetches the scope specific RDD and spawns a job
2. On each RDD, do a join with the new RDD having changes
3. now I do all the computations again on this new RDD at step2 like multiplication, reduction etc

**Approach 3:**

I had thought of creating streaming RDD where I keep updating the same RDD and do re-computation. But as far as I understand it can take streams from Flume or Kafka. Whereas in my case the values are generated in the application itself based on user interaction.
Hence I cannot see any integration points of streaming RDD in my context.

Any suggestion on which approach is better or any other approach suitable for this scenario.

TIA!

Answer (score 9):

The usecase presented here is a good match for Spark Streaming. The two other options bear the question: "How do you submit a re-computation of the RDD?"

Spark Streaming offers a framework to continuously submit work to Spark based on some stream of incoming data and preserve that data in RDD form. Kafka and Flume are only two possible Stream sources.

You could use Socket communication with the [SocketInputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/SocketInputDStream.scala), reading files in a directory using [FileInputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala) or even using shared Queue with the [QueueInputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/QueueInputDStream.scala). If none of those options fit your application, you could write your own [InputDStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/InputDStream.scala).

In this usecase, using Spark Streaming, you will read your base RDD and use the incoming dstream to incrementally transform the existing data and maintain an evolving in-memory state. `dstream.transform` will allow you to combine the base RDD with the data collected during a given batch interval, while the `updateStateByKey` operation could help you build an in-memory state addressed by keys. See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams) for further information.

Without more details on the application is hard to go up to the code level on what's possible using Spark Streaming. I'd suggest you to explore this path and make new questions for any specific topics.

Comment: Thanks @maasg. Regarding your question "How do you submit re-computation" I have edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried prototyping some of these ideas? It would be much clearer in some code. e.g. Not sure how you're planning to implement "I Save this RDDs reference" and how is that going to help. You will need to do caching as well otherwise the RDD will be recomputed from scratch. Looking into the Spark Job Server could be another option: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at [IndexedRDD implementation](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd/blob/master/src/main/scala/edu/berkeley/cs/amplab/spark/indexedrdd/IndexedRDD.scala), which provides updatable RDD of key value pairs. That might give you some insights.

The idea is based on the knowledge of the key and that allows you to zip your updated chunk of data with the same keys of already created RDD. During update it's possible to filter out previous version of the data.

Having historical data, I'd say you have to have sort of identity of an event.

Regarding streaming and consumption, it's possible to use TCP port. This way the driver might open a TCP connection spark expects to read from and sends updates there.